# Symfony2 extension, replaceArgument

Tags: php, symfony

I'm working with Symfony2 and I'm trying to setup a service definition overriding.

The extension is correctly loaded but the service definition not changed.

Here is the code:

```
class AppExtension extends Extension
{
    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function load(array $configs, ContainerBuilder $container)
    {
        $configuration = new Configuration();
        $config = $this->processConfiguration($configuration, $configs);

        $loader = new Loader\YamlFileLoader($container, new FileLocator(__DIR__.'/../Resources/config'));
        $loader->load('services.yml');

        $container->setParameter('app.comment.delay_between', $config['comment']['delay_between']);

        $def = $container->getDefinition('app.comment.manager')
            ->replaceArgument(0, $config['comment']);

        $container->setDefinition('app.comment.manager2', $def);
    }

    /**
     * {@inheritdoc}
     */
    public function getAlias() {
        return 'app';
    }
}
```

The service definition:

```
app.comment.manager:
    class: AppBundle\Comment\CommentManager
    arguments:
        - []
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

And the constructor of the class CommentManager:

```
/**
 * CommandManager constructor.
 * @param array $config
 * @param EntityManagerInterface $em
 */
public function __construct(array $config, EntityManagerInterface $em) {
    $this->config = $config;
    var_dump($config);
    $this->em = $em;
}
```

And in the controller I call:

```
$this->get('app.comment.manager');
$this->get('app.comment.manager2');
```

And I get this result:

```
/home/nathan/Dev/click-tube/src/symfony/src/AppBundle/Comment/CommentManager.php:37:
array (size=0)
  empty
/home/nathan/Dev/click-tube/src/symfony/src/AppBundle/Comment/CommentManager.php:37:
array (size=1)
  'delay_between' => int 60
```

As you can see, I can't modify the app.commment.manager service definition (which is what I want to do). But I can reflect the changes on a extension-created service.
What is the solution to apply the changes on app.comment.manager?

Answer (score 1):

Try inject in the service the parameter defined in the extension, as example:

```
app.comment.manager:
    class: AppBundle\Comment\CommentManager
    arguments:
        - "%app.comment.delay_between%"
        - "@doctrine.orm.entity_manager"
```

Hope this help

Comment: Thank you, I already thought of doing that but I'm really wondering why the method replaceArgument doesn't work for this service, according to the doc it is possible ( http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/dependency_injection/definitions.html#getting-and-setting-service-definitions ).

Answer (score 0):

I have had the same issue where the replaceArgument call didn't really modify the arguments given to the constructor of my service. The reason was that my services.yml was already imported in my /app/config/config.yml like:

```
imports:
    - { resource: parameters.yml }
    - { resource: security.yml }
    - { resource: services.yml }
    - { resource: "@MyMightyBundle/Resources/config/services.yml" }
```

This would override the service definition loaded in met bundle extension file. Removing the service.yml import in my config.yml solved my problem.